# Out of 100 students, 50 like C++, 50 like ruby and 30 like both.

Tags: probability

Out of 100 students, 50 like C++, 50 like ruby and 30 like both. The conditional probability that a student likes C++ given that she likes ruby is:

A/ 0.3

B/ 0.4

C/ 0.5

D/ 0.6

Just wonder if the answer is D? If it is not, can anyone explain why please?
THANKS

Comment: This problem is baloney. Everyone likes C++! ;)

Comment: Also everyone like rubies. But not everyone like rugby.

Comment: What about the other 30 students that do not like neither C++ nor Ruby ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember Bayes' Rule:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

$$P(C|R) = \frac{P(C \cap R)}{P(R)} = \frac{0.3}{0.5} = \frac{3}{5} = \frac{6}{10} = 0.6$$

Comment: THANK YOU. JUST WANT HAVE SOMEONE TO CONFIRM!

Comment: Confirmed.  Also, your caps lock is on.